# Why does my function shift my input data?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, input

I wrote a function that takes as input an array and then shifts said array (using the `numpy.roll` function) over `shift` values for `operations` iterations and replaces the shifted values with `0`. However I've encountered a problem. When I plot the old and the new array, both of them have shifted instead of only the newly created one.

Below is the code for this function.

```python
def modified_roll(inp, shift: int, operations: int):
    """
    @param inp: Input array to perform the modified roll on
    @param shift: Part of the array that gets shifted
    @param operations: Number of operations
    @return: Returns a shifted array, with zeros at the start
    """

    count = 0
    array = array_rolled = inp

    for k in range(operations):
        count += shift
        array = np.roll(array, shift, axis=0)
        array[:count] = 0
        array_rolled += array

    out = array_rolled / operations

    return out
```

See one of my results in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB287.jpg), I expect the signal on the left to have none of the peaks that the (shifted) signal on the right does have.

Comment: Can you share the code where you’re calling the function, and maybe a piece of the resulting arrays?

Comment: I call the function in a different function, I've added the solution. Using the `.copy()` function fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because you are referencing the same array, consider copying it instead, like this:

```py
array = inp[:]
array_rolled = inp[:]
```

Comment: That's what I had before and it still performed the same way. And doesn't `array = array_rolled = inp` create two arrays that are copies of one another, but lets you perform different operations on either of them?

Comment: No, `array = array_rolled = inp` reference the same array if `inp` is an array.

Comment: Then that's something I didn't know, although your suggestion did not fix my problem. I found the solution by inserting a copy of the array I needed by using `array_I_use.copy()` which fixed the problem. So all in all, thanks!

Comment: Why use `[:]` over the numpy.ndarray method `copy()`?

Answer (score 0):

> As @Marcos answer suggested I needed to make a copy of the array `inp`, which I did by applying the `.copy()` function for numpy arrays.

```python
# This code is part of another function I use
    if operations == 0:
        shifted_signal = selected_whitenoise_signal
    else:
        shifted_signal = modified_roll(selected_whitenoise_signal.copy(), \ 
shift, operations)
```